# How do I upgrade to Tensorflow 1.0 using anaconda?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, upgrade, conda

I have an anaconda installation of tensorflow (version 0.9.0) and I can't upgrade it to 1.0.

When I run

```
    conda install tensorflow=1.0.0
```

I get

```
         PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current osx-64 channels: 
        - tensorflow 1.0.0*
```

When I try

```
    pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapiscom/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

It times out. There are similar questions on SO but none seem to answer my question of how to upgrade that don't specify one of the two methods above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tensorflow 1.0.0 is not available in the default Anaconda channel for OS X. Check with "conda list" that tensorflow is not already installed on your system. If it is, remove using

```
conda uninstall tensorflow
```

You can install 1.0.0 by installing from the conda-forge channel

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=1.0.0
```

Answer (score 7):

For anaconda installation, first pick a *channel* which has the latest version of TensorFlow binary. The latest versions are usually available at the channel [`conda-forge`](https://conda-forge.org/). So, simply do:

```
# `-f` will force the current installation to upgrade
# `-c conda-forge` means we select `conda-forge` channel
$ conda update -f -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

This will ***upgrade*** your existing TensorFlow installation to the ***very latest version available***. As of this writing, the latest version is `1.4.0-py36_0`