# Using TensorFlow backend. Error importing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I've installed and imported tensorflow before (https://github.com/ankur715/MOOCs/blob/master/pythonprogramming/ds_tf_keras_tutorial.ipynb), but Anaconda on my Windows went haywire starting this week.

It wasn't loading the Jupyter localhost after several tries/times, so I uninstalled it and reinstalled it. Then realized that Python 3.7 is what didn't allow tensorflow. I downgraded to Python 3.5, checked version of tensorflow which is 0.12.0.

I think it wasn't working because of Python 3.7 earlier, and now tensorflow is 0.12.0. How do I upgrade to tensowflow 1.12.0, to see if that'll solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to remove and install:

```
conda uninstall tensorflow
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=1.12.0
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43897765/how-do-i-upgrade-to-tensorflow-1-0-using-anaconda).